# Simultaniously read accelerometer and gyroscope

Tags: android

I tried to extend the Android sample under movesense-mobile-lib so that it reads accelerometer and gyroscope simultaniously. To do that I subscribed to both

/Device/Measurement/LinearAcceleration and
/Device/Measurement/AngularVelocity

However, only one of the streams is read. How can I read both sources simultaniously?

[movesense](/questions/tagged/movesense)

Comment: How did you figure out the URI for angular velocity?  Are those paths documented somewhere?  Only the linear acceleration URI is mentioned in the sample apps, as far as I can see.

Comment: I got it from https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: The issue has been fixed in the latest movesense-mobile-lib release**

The multiple streams work by subscribing to both paths just as you assumed and you should be getting both callbacks. However it looks like there is a bug in Android mobile library and this does not actually work.

I've entered an issue in the bug tracker so you can follow the progress:

https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-mobile-lib/issues/9/simultaneous-subscription-to

Simultaneous Accelerometer & Gyro subscription and data analysis should get easier when the (6- and 9-axis) IMU interface is implemented in *Movesense device lib*, but you can also make your own combining service that combines the data from Acceleration and AngularVelocity and use that until the bugfix or IMU service is released.

*Full disclosure: I work for Movesense team*

Comment: The issue has been fixed in the recent movesense-mobile-lib update